# Setting group for all files and folders with rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, rsync

I'm sending some files to my production server with `rsync` and would like to ensure that all users in a group can perform the deploy.

How can I ensure that the rsync script sets both:

- The correct group (www-data)
- The correct permissions (read,write,execute for all members of the www-data group)

So far, the command looks like this, and uploads the files, and sets the permissions that I'd like. However, `I'm not sure how to set the group for every single file and folder, recursively.`

```
rsync -rvp --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o=rx public/ myuser@123.12.12.123:/var/www/mysite
```

I've read you can use the `--chown` option, but that keeps giving me the following error: `no matches found: --usermap=*:www-data`

What's going wrong? Here's the last command that I tried:

`rsync -rv -og --usermap=:www-data --groupmap=:www-data --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o=rx public/ slave:/var/www/mysite.com`

Comment: Does `--chmod` not work or `--usermap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the command that I ended up using. For some reason, my shell was expanding the --chmod command and failing (due to the *).

```
rsync -rv -og --usermap="\*:www-data" --groupmap="\*:www-data" --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o=rx public/ myuser@123.12.12.134:/var/www/mysite
```